# How many calories should I exactly eat for building body?

Tags: diet, bodybuilding

The title is little ambiguous. But my situation puts that into context:

My weight 60kgs & height 5'6". 
I've started weight training for body building for past 3 weeks. Its written every where to eat huge. So I started eating huge. My typical diet contains:

```
Chicken 150-200gms
Rice 400-500gms
Eggs 1-2
Milk 250ml
Oil/Butter/Fat 30-40gms
Some Vegetable (100gms)
Multivitamin capsules (covers 30%-70% of different vitamins & minerals)
Calcium supplement (500mgx2)
```

This amounts to around 2800-3000 calories. 
I work 3 days a week in gym (for 2-2.5hrs) and otherwise I just sit infront of desk (so other 4 days is strictly sitting at desk). Here is my workout of past 4 workout days: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2Q2be3Th

Good thing is that, I've gained weight. My arms, chest, lats thighs (credit goes to squats) got bulked up. I'm happy but I've accumulated quite a bit of fat around my belly. Even though I've very thin body, I've quite a bit of fat around my abodmen, especially in lower abdomen area (hereditary). Now in this past 3 weeks this increased quite a bit.

This is raising doubts about my diet. Am I eating too much? Should I reduce my carbs? Am I eating enough? How many calories should I exactly eat for building body? Also because I'm not doing anything except sitting, during 4 days a week should I eat less during these rest days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has protein, carbs, and vegetables and nutritiance! not gaining minimal fat whilst gaining muscle is impossible... don't stress :) per pound of muscle you gain your body burns an extra 80 cal per day... so don't stress about weight just keep lifting and eating big and the weight will sort it self out :) if not go on a cutting phase in a few weeks,

Comment: can you give some scientific evidence to `not gaining minimal fat whilst gaining muscle is impossible`

Comment: or you could type in "is it impossible to gain muscle and lose body fat at the same time?" into google/google scholar. and get all the evidence you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus less on the number of calories, and more on **what** foods your eating, and **when** your are eating them.

After training, eat some proteins and some complex carbonhydrates, such as rice, bread, fruits, etc. If you work out for 2 hours a time, try to grab a banana or something during training.

Otherwise, stick to meats and vegetables. **You don't want to eat a lot of carbohydrates on days your not training, try to stick to a few pieces of fruit.**

It is a huge and complex area, but try to look into more information about nutritional timing.

Comment: Here is my problem, when people suggest "a lot" or "not a lot", I don't know how much is "a lot" or "not a lot".

Comment: It is because it is dependent on so many factors you cannot give a generic number. Your lifestyle, your weight, your musclemass, and a lot of other variables come into play. You could find a professional to help you with.

Comment: I can't find a professional :( Can this be done online somewhere? Just some approximate numbers would do.

Comment: You should not focus on an specific amount of calories. I will not work. You should focus on eating clean, and eating at the right times. Don't eat carbohydrates if you have not trained. Make sure to weigh yourself each week, at the same time. If your loosing weight, you need to eat some more - clean foods - and if your gaining more than 1 kilogram pr. month you need to cut back a little. Take measurements of your body with a tape. Good mass comes on the arms, chest and thighs. Bad mass comes on the stomach.